# "Don't cut yourself on that edge"

Tags: idioms

What does the idiom *don't cut yourself on that edge* mean? I have seen it being used on multiple occasions, but could not find anything on the web that explains this idiom.

Comment: I haven't seen it before. Please can you find some examples and post them in your question together with their URLs? Thanks.

Comment: What, you've never cut yourself on an edge??

Comment: Is it referring to "the bleeding edge" of the latest (not tried and true) technologies?

Comment: Sometimes used sarcastically, where the edge in question is quite blunt, but there's a possibility that you're just dumb enough to hurt yourself on it anyway.  Context will offer clues as to whether this is how the phrase is meant.

Comment: None of these answers are correct, why was the question closed?  The expression is a reference to someone acting in an "edgy" manner, such as saying something controversial, and mocking them for it.  It's from `edgy adjective 3. having a bold, provocative, or unconventional quality 'an edgy film'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is, say, a piece of sheet metal somewhere, it might have a sharp edge.  Were one to accidentally rub their arm against this edge they might get a nasty cut.

So, "Don't cut yourself on that edge" simply means that one should beware of the sharp edge being pointed out to you.

However, let's say you're in a bar with a buddy and you see and are attracted to a woman who your buddy knows is the girlfriend of a mobster.  He might say "Don't cut yourself on that edge" to warn you that you're playing with fire.  (Though his use of that idiom suggests that he already knows you will probably ignore his advice.)

(In real life I suspect the idiom is more likely to be used to warn someone that the person they're attracted to is a heart-breaker.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess It means you have not to do something because you will suffer from this.

Comment: Can you provide evidence to back up your guess?

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonably sure the sense of 'edge' meant in the first instance is {[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/edge)}

**edge** n. 1.

> d. A slight but noticeable sharpness, harshness, or discomforting
>   quality: *His voice had an edge to it.*

(though

> c. A penetrating, incisive quality: "His simplicity sets off the
>   satire, and gives it a finer edge" (William Hazlitt). {AHDEL}

is just possible).

So I'd say the expression, directed at someone showing harshness, is a punning rebuke.

I doubt that the 'incisiveness' sense is involved; if it were, the expression would be akin to 'You're so sharp you'll cut yourself one day.'